# Проверка на полную прозрачность картинки в Javascript (canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas

Я пытаюсь реализовать при помощи canvas функционал стирания изображения  ластиком.
Я создаю canvas и задаю ему background в CSS. Поверх canvas я делаю `drawImage` png картинки с прозрачностью, к которой я применяю ластик. Мне нужно проверить, стерта ли картинка полностью, то есть полностью ли прозрачный фон, и осуществить дальше какое-то действие.

Мой метод создания канваса, отрисовки png на нем и процесса стирания:

```
var img = new Image;
var canvas = {};

function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {

    canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');

    img.onload = function(){
    canvas.context.drawImage(img,200,0,img.width*1.2,img.height*1.2); // Or at whatever offset you like
    };
    img.src = 'raccoon.png';

    canvas.node.width = width || 100;
    canvas.node.height = height || 100;
    parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
    return canvas;
}

function init(container, width, height, fillColor) {
    var canvas = createCanvas(container, width, height);
    var ctx = canvas.context;
    // define a custom fillCircle method
    ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
        this.fillStyle = fillColor;
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x, y);
        this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        this.fill();
    };
    ctx.clearTo = function(fillColor) {
        ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    };

    // bind mouse events
    canvas.node.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
           return;
        }
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        var radius = 80; // or whatever
        var fillColor = '#000000';
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
        ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
    };
    canvas.node.onmousedown = function(e) {
        canvas.isDrawing = true;
    };
    canvas.node.onmouseup = function(e) {
        canvas.isDrawing = false;
        if (isFullyTransparent()) {
            redirect();
        };
    };

}

function isFullyTransparent() {
var d = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
for (var i=3; i < d.length; i+=4)
if (d[i]) 
  return false
return true
}

function redirect() {
    };

var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
init(container, 1024, 768, '');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка для примера. Нужен метод, проверяющий, стерт енот полностью или нет.

Comment: неплохо бы еще код, которым изображение стирается

Comment: я изменил ответ

Comment: добавил код в вопрос

Comment: ну Вы не трогаете прозрачность...

Comment: Не совсем понял, где я не трогаю прозрачность? Я разместил пока только свой код, не Ваш. У меня фон, задаваемый в css. Поверх него я кладу png фигурку енота с прозрачностью. Стираю. Нужно проверить, все стерто или нет.

Comment: Мой метод проверяет прозрачность пикселя, а Вы, когда  стираете не  меняете ее значение на 0, а просто меняете цвет пикселей, попробуйте рисовать круг цветом `#0000` или `transparent`

Comment: я изменил ответ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно проверить все пиксели на прозрачность при помощи их перебора и поиска не 0 значения:

Рисовать левой кнопкой мыши, стирать - правой

```js
var img = new Image;
var canvas = {};

function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
    canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
    img.onload = function() {
      canvas.context.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height); 
      canvas.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    };
    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/GtBHNPS.png';
    canvas.node.width = width || 100;
    canvas.node.height = height || 100;
    parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
    return canvas;
}

function init(container, width, height, fillColor) {
    var canvas = createCanvas(container, width, height);
    var ctx = canvas.context;
    ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
        this.fillStyle = fillColor;
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x, y);
        this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        this.fill();
    };
    ctx.clearTo = function(fillColor) {
        ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    };
    canvas.node.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (!canvas.isDrawing) 
           return;
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        var radius = 80; 
        var fillColor = '#fff';
        ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
    };
    canvas.node.onmousedown = function(e) {
        canvas.isDrawing = true;
    };
    canvas.node.onmouseup = function(e) {
        canvas.isDrawing = false;
        if (isFullyTransparent()) {
            redirect();
        };
    };
}

function isFullyTransparent() {
  var d = canvas.context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.node.width, canvas.node.height).data;
  for (var i=3; i < d.length; i+=4)
  if (d[i]) 
    return false
  return true
}

function redirect() {
  alert('redirect')
}

init(document.body, 350, 350);
```

```css
body{
  background: #000a;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. 1-й блок - в код скрипта, второй в CSS, третий - в html-часть. Правильно? А вызываю этот метод вот так? 
canvas.node.onmouseup = function(e) {
            canvas.isDrawing = false;
            if (isFullyTransparent(canvas)) {
                redirect();
            };
        };
Пока что не работает.

Comment: @МихаилФогель в целом да, добавьте код в вопрос, а я уточню ответ